# (What do we know about) the c.d.f. of a smooth function on another distribution with a smooth c.d.f

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability

Given that $1\leq k< d$, let $X$ be a random vector with a c.d.f. $f\in\mathscr C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R\right)$, also let $\Psi\in\mathscr C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^k\right)$. Suppose that $\mathrm {rank}\left(\Psi\right)=k$ in $\mathbb R^d$, then what do we know about the distribution of $Y=\Psi\left(X\right)$? Does $Y$ always have a c.d.f.? If so, will the c.d.f. always be smooth?

Comment: What are $s,t,\mathrm {rank}\left(\Psi\right)$? Is $X$ a distribution or a random vector? If $X$ is a distribution, then what is $\Psi\left(X\right)$? This post requires further work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've edited the problem.

Comment: Yet, what is $\mathrm {rank}\left(\Psi\right)$?

Comment: Also, **any** random vector in $\mathbb R^k$ has a (joint) c.d.f.